# Debugging integrated Windows authentication in .NET Core Weblistener app

Tags: asp.net-core, owin, kerberos, windows-authentication, weblistener

I have a .NET Core application using OWIN and windows authentication with `AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate`, hosted on Weblistener rather than IIS.

In some setups, this just works, whereas in others, a login prompt is shown, and the user cannot be authenticated. However, I never know **why** it works or why it doesn't.

How would I **debug** such a problem in a production environment, and what could I change in the application to make it debuggable in production? What logs can I look at, where can I enable additional logging, etc.? Are there any built-in ways of changing application settings related to authentication in production (other than changing the code, or adding custom code to make it configurable, or hosting it on IIS?)

NOTE: I'm **not** interested in how to "fix" the problem, as it can have many different causes and pops up here and there on many different servers.

More details:

- Visual Studio 2015
- 1.0.0-preview2-003131 (Seriously?!)
- The app only has one endpoint and does not use cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is easier to debug by eliminating unknowns, such as the .NET Core application. Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) in WebListener (or HttpSysServer or Kestrel) is not much different from IWA in IIS. So a first step is to replicate the issue by setting up an empty IIS website, application or virtual directory with IWA enabled and anonymous authentication disabled and a binding to the same host name as the real application.

If the issue can be replicated, then IIS offers better ways to debug the problem (such as failed request tracing - which is totally not helpful, or using NTLM instead of Negotiate as the preferred provider, or disabling kernel mode, etc.).

If Kerberos is used (which is highly likely in production), then Kerberos logging can be enabled on the client machine by creating a registry value in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters` with name `LogLevel`, type `DWORD` and value `0x1`, according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/262177/how-to-enable-kerberos-event-logging. Kerberos events can then be seen in the `System` log with Event Viewer.

If the issue can not be replicated in IIS, then there is a problem with the .NET Core application, but this is unlikely, because setting up IWA in the application code is straightforward and almost impossible to do wrong. If it works on one system and not on another, it probably has to do with Kerberos, AD, host names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know a few things,

1. What version of Visual Studio?
2. What version of.NET Core

> the user cannot be authenticated

Are you using cookies?

> What logs can I look at

you can enable logging in appsettings.json

[Logging in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

outside of that you can look at the event Viewer for asp.net entries

outside of all of this, different browsers will handle these requests differently,  if it works in one browser but not in another i'd start there

Comment: Thanks so far. If the .NET Core logging infrastructure wasn't so horribly bloated and complicated, it would have been the first thing I tried, but I'm still not sure if I can expect to find anything relevant to authentication in those logs.

Comment: I would update from 1.0.0-preview2-003131 to at least 2.0.

Comment: Now that I have dug into the logging article, it looks like this allows me to add my own log message. This is not helpful though. User authentication happens within code that isn't part of the application, but part of the framework / OS / web server. Is there a way to make these components produce logs? There are no asp.net entries in the event viewer.